# Excel TEXT formula doesn't convert 'yyyy' to a year

Tags: excel, date, date-formatting

I want to combine some text with a date in Excel 2013.

Let's say I have a cell A2 with a date like *30-10-2014*. I tried to append the date after the text with this formula:
`="Some text and a date: "&A2`

But the output shows the date as a number: *Some text and a date: 41942*

So I tried it with the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) formula:
`="Some text and a date: "&TEXT(A2;"dd-mm-yyyy")`

But this shows *Some text and a date: 30-10-yyyy* and not *Some text and a date: 30-10-2014*

So or I do not understand how the `TEXT` formula works or is there some bug / issue here?

**UPDATE**: It looks like it's important that I have a Dutch version of Windows (7) but an English version of Excel (2013) which causes this issue!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All kudos go to @AxelRichter, thanks Axel!

It looks like that if you have a Dutch Windows but an English version of Excel (2013) the formulas get mixed up. For example, I still have the English formula names like `TEXT` (which would be `TEKST` in Dutch) but still have to use a colon instead of a comma in the formula. The *format_text* value of `TEXT` still expects the Dutch format which is different for the year (*jjjj* instead of *yyyy*).

So if you have a Dutch Windows and an English Excel version the correct formula for some text followed by a formatted date would be:

`="Some text and a date: "&TEXT(A2;"dd-mm-jjjj")`

I hope Microsoft will fix this, this is very annoying!

Comment: The format pattern for dates comes from the Windows locale settings and have to be "dd-mm-jjjj"; [d]ag [m]aand [j]aar if it is a Netherlands Windows. Also the formula delimiter (list delimiter) is ";" per default in Netherlands Windows. Only the function name TEXT comes from the English Excel. So there is nothing to fix for Microsoft ;-).

And, no, the string within the TEXT function =TEXT(A1;"dd-mm-jjjj") will not change automatically if someone uses other locale settings. This is one of the disadvantages of the TEXT function.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks again for your detailed explanation, do you also know how to change the locale settings for this in Windows?

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible to change the date/time pattern without changing the whole locale to another language. The list delimiter is changeable http://www.solveyourtech.com/change-the-windows-7-list-separator/ But this not really makes sense in my opinion. It only increases the confusion because it often comes in conflict with the decimal separator which can not be the same as the list separator.

Comment: OK, in that case I'll keep in mind not to mix the OS language with the Excel language next time ;-)

Comment: @AlexRichter, you wrote "there's nothing to fix for Microsoft" - well, there's definitely something they could improve. Even if they insist on localizing the format specification (y vs j), then they should provide a way to suppress that - e.g. allow an argument specifying the locale. Or simply providing a function which always takes the same format (the English one). Otherwise you end up with a nightmare of the same file looking differently on different computers.

Comment: For PT-BR: AAAA

Comment: This almost drove me nuts. C'mon MS, fix this damn thing !!! up-voted <3

Comment: @AxelRichter, This is definitely an issue with the TEXT() function if you are sending the same Excel document to various people with different locales (which you cannot control). There should be locale-independent formatting strings.

Comment: I have tried RRRR but never guessed jjjj
thank you very much :)

Comment: what if its a shared document and people are using it in different countries. is there any generalized formula so that id doesn't feel invalid for other countries.

Answer (score 16):

You can now use 'e' instead of 'yyyy'. The e is the universal version of yyyy a

Comment: Do you have a link to the source?

Comment: Are there similar variants for `mm` and `dd`?

Answer (score 6):

we have the same issue at our work and I found that if I cannot influence the localization of the windows then I use a formula which in your case looks like:

```
="Some text and a date: "&TEXT(A2;"dd-mm-")&YEAR(A2)
```

It is funny that "dd" and "mm" is the same.

Comment: It's not "funny", it's what Dutch words are: day = dag, month = maand. Try a German local and "dd" will stop working (day = Tag).

Comment: This worked for me on US-EN on Spain-Spanish PC. What a mess this was.

Answer (score 2):

Excel here obviously fails. TEXT should be language agnostic.

The workaround I found, especially if you have multiple cells to format:

1. Calculate the desired date format in a hidden cell or white colored:

`=IF(TYPE(VALUE(TEXT(DATE_CELL;"YY")))=1;"DD.MM.YYYY";"ДД.ММ.ГГГГ")`

If you need, it can be extended to support multiple regions like:

`=IF(TYPE(VALUE(TEXT(DATE_CELL;"YY")))=1;"DD.MM.YYYY";IF(TYPE(VALUE(TEXT(DATE_CELL;"ГГ")))=1;"ДД.ММ.ГГГГ";"DD.MM.JJJJ"))`

2. On cells where you need dates, use previous cell as second parameter:

`="Date: " & TEXT(DATE_CELL; FORMAT_CELL)`

Answer (score 2):

This should work regardless of your system language or regional settings:

```
="Some text and a date: "&TEXT(DAY(A2);"00")&"-"&TEXT(MONTH(A2);"00")&"-"&TEXT(YEAR(A2);"0000")
```

[Click here to see it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48ZS8.png)

[Edit] I just tested the solution with German (TT.MM.JJJJ) and English settings (DD.MM.YYYY) and it works fine!
You may need to use **,** instead of **;** in the MS EXCEL formula (depending on your actual list separator symbol --> check your OS settings!).

Comment: It looks a bit ugly, but your solution is the only one that works on a wide range of Excel versions and Windows locales without resorting to macros (often limited for security reasons) or named functions (a less "in the face" redirect, tougher to spot cell dependencies with in Trace Dependents and therefore harder to set-up).

Answer (score 1):

For same problem when your system or keyboard is Danish then use åååå in place of jjjj. I also struggled a lot to find this key. 
However if anyone facing same problem apart from Dutch or Danish then you can check which key is correct.  To find it right click on any cell and goto 'Format Cell' then select 'Custom' and find date related formats in your local language. There you can find which is the right key to be used for DATE format in your local language.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is still there on Excel 2016 (or Office 365, if you may). It is caused by different language settings in Windows. This happens for languages that have different year symbols (dutch is 'jjjj', portuguese is 'aaaa'). If you're experiencing this problem, try using your local Windows language's year format.

Answer (score 1):

My computer is set to English (German). I had to use tt/MM/jjjj. Carefully note its MM not mm.

Comment: 'German' English? What is German English?

Comment: It's one of the language options in windows. Possibly English with German number and date formats, etc.

Comment: I'm asking because I speak American English, but I've also heard of UK English, Australian English, Canadian English IRCC, but I have not heard of German English.

Comment: "English (Germany)" is a language configuration that one can install on Windows, see [this screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20240116122527/https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/111/765/611/329/959/603/original/955dbd1ff7607a5c.png). It likely works similar to my "English (Netherlands)" setting, Excel uses `j` for year instead of `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: To check if "jjjj" format is working:

The date you want to display in a certain format is in A1

In cell A2 link a cel to the cel with the date you want displayed in a certain format with the following formula:

```
=TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")
```

In a 3rd cel you then place the following formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2;4)="jjjj";TEXT(A1;"yyyy");TEXT(A1;"jjjj"))
```

If the 4 digits from the right are "jjjj" this formula will display the date formatted as "yyyy" else the formatting "jjjj" will be used.

Comment: What if your companion uses the Bengali locale or the Russian one? (And you don't know in advance or ever.)

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix, whether directly custom formatting a cell or using `TEXT()`, is to use a country code for a language you know the proper formatting codes for.

For instance, I am in the US, have a US version of Excel, and am familiar with its date code formats. So I'd want to use them and to ensure they "come out" regardless of anyone's Windows or Excel version, or the country they are in, I'd do it like the following (for `TEXT()`, let's say, but it'd be the same idea in custom formatting):

```
=TEXT(A1,[$-en-US]"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

The function would collect the value in A1, ask Excel to treat it as a date, Excel would and would say fine, it's cool (i.e.:  the value is, say, 43857 and not "horse") because it is a positive number which is a requirement for anything to be treated as a date, and let the function move on to rendering it as a date in the manner prescribed. Rather than  giving an `#ERROR!` as it would for "horse" or -6.

The function would then read the formatting string and see the language code. It would then drop the usual set of formatting codes it loaded upon starting up and load in the formatting codes for English ("en") and in particular, US English ("US"). The rest of the string uses codes from that set so it would interpret them properly and send an appropriate string back to `TEXT()` for it to display in the cell (and pass on to other formulas if such exist).

I have no way to test the following, but I assume that if one were to use a format that displayed day of the week names or month names, they would be from the same language set. In other words, Excel would not think that even though you specified a country and language that you still wanted, say, Dutch or Congolese month names. So that kind of thing would still need addressed, but would be an easy fix too just involving, say, a simple lookup one could add though it'd be "fun" setting up the lookup table for each language one wanted to accomodate...

However, the basic issue that arises here, and with this problem in general, is very, very easily solved with the country codes. They aren't even hard or arcane anymore now that the `[$-409]` syntax has been replaced with things like `[$-en-us]` and `[$-he-IL]` and so on.

Comment: English Excel, German OS `=TEXT(DATE(2021;11;25);"[$-en-us]ddd")`  returns `ddd`; `=TEXT(DATE(2021;11;25);"[$-en-us]ttt")` returns `Thu` and `=TEXT(DATE(2021;11;25);"ttt")` returns `Do`. The [$-en-us] part only controls the output, not the recognition of a format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

If VBA is an option... works for any locale/language

```
Public Function dateYYYYMMDD(dt As Date) As String
    dateYYYYMMDD = Format(dt, "yyyyMMDD")
End Function
```