# Excel format date from DATEVALUE to TEXT with formula

Tags: excel, date, formula

I have date that I get from *Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP4)* and it goes to cell A1 so cell A1 result is **9.10.2018**. Then I use formula to convert it to needed format in cell A2 `=DATEVALUE(A1)` and A2 is set to *Format cells* *-> Specific Date Format* so I am getting as a result **09 October 2018**. 
Now I am writing specific text in cell A3 that combines several cells with formula:
`=Data!J23&" "&LOWER(Data!J30)&" member since "&A2`

I get: *Permanent full time member since **43421***

I need it to be: *Permanent full time member since **09 October 2018***

Comment: Converting it stores it as a date format for excel, which is the amount of days since an arbitrary starting point I can't recall right now. Hence the 43421. Use the  `TEXT()` formula to display your date correctly, see https://www.contextures.com/xlCombine01.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have tried `=TEXT(A1;"mm/dd/yyyy")` but I get _00/dd/yyyy_

Comment: You should try that with A2, where you formatted your text to date first, as you described in your question.

Comment: Same result with A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you from? Try this one out.

Here is the link for the hint: 
[Original post with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306317/excel-text-formula-doesnt-convert-yyyy-to-a-year)

In my case I am using "Finnish windows" but what is confusing  is that actually Windows is English version and all the programs are on English (Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc.). The only thing that I am located in Finland and using Finnish keyboard but everything in my computer is on English. Anyway you have to use your country specific "date code" `=Data!J23&" "&LOWER(Data!J30)&" member since "&TEXT(A2;"pp.kk.vvvv")`

So instead of `dd.mm.yyyy`

You have to use `pp.kk.vvvv` (at least here, in Finland).

Because *pp* = päivä, *kk* = kuukausi, *vvvv* = vuosi